# Ear file installation through jython giving issue in websphere application server startup

Tags: python, websphere, jython

hi i have a below logic to install both war and ear files being in warpath into websphere.
after running the script it installs both war and ears successfully but during server stratup its throwing error only for ear file.
if i use same commandlogic to execute directly on wsadmin for ear file installation it works fine and even server comes up without error,can any one analyse whats going wrong in the script

ERROR:org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [netbanksrv.context]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'netbanksrv.context' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere8/AppServer/Profiles/AppSrv12/installedApps/BLRVSWASBFT01Node10Cell/netbanksrv-ear.ear/lib/netbanksrv-core-5.4.3.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [pegasus.framework.spring.context.MethodCachingClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genAccountServices.WSDLResource' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere8/AppServer/Profiles/AppSrv12/installedApps/BLRVSWASBFT01Node10Cell/netbanksrv-ear.ear/lib/integration-1.3.0.jar!/META-INF/spring/AccountServices-ws-springintegration.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [pegasus.integration.framework.HttpClientUrlResource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: null

## my logic:

```
for fname in os.listdir(warPath):
        if fname.endswith(".ear") or fname.endswith(".war"):
            file_list.append(fname)


    for i in range(len(file_list)):
        earFile=file_list[i]
        letter=earFile[0]

        if (letter == "a"):
            applicationName="admin-guiwar"
            installApp(cellName, nodeName, serverName, earFile, applicationName);
            classldr(applicationName)
        if (letter == "i"):
            applicationName="internetbank-guiwar"
            installApp(cellName, nodeName, serverName, earFile, applicationName);
            classldr(applicationName)
        if (letter == "m"):
            applicationName="mobilegateway"
            installApp(cellName, nodeName, serverName, earFile, applicationName);
            classldr(applicationName)
        if (letter == "n"):
            applicationName="netbanksrv-ear"
            installApp(cellName, nodeName, serverName, earFile, applicationName);
            classldr(applicationName)

def installApp (cellName, nodeName, serverName, warFileName, applicationName):
    fullPath = warPath+"/"+warFileName
    node = "-node "+nodeName
    cell = "-cell "+cellName
    svr = "-server "+serverName
    appName = "-appname "+applicationName
    AdminApp.install(fullPath, [node, cell, svr, appName])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deploy script is OK. But you have a different issue with Spring:

```
 Could not instantiate bean class [pegasus.integration.framework.HttpClientUrlResource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: null
```

I think you have to set class loader policy to `PARENT_LAST` for your application.

[WAS Classloader Best Practices](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006994&aid=1)

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply.i have written a code to do the class loading to parent last .still it gives me same error.if i use same admin config command for installing the ear file outside it works fine

Comment: i am not able to make out whats going wrong.same admin config installs war file for which i am not getting the issue only for ear file its throwing above issue

Comment: This is a link to Classloader Best Practices: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006994&aid=1. It should help.